# How to create service first soap webservice using spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-ws

We can see many tutorials that shows how to produce soap webservice using xsd in spring-boot. Is it possible to create soap webservice without xsd and from plain Java code using spring-boot-webservice module like we do using @webservice annotation in jax-ws

Comment: Does it have to be a SOAP complaint web service, or is it enough to have a REST service that return XML ?

Comment: It should be SOAP complaint web service

Answer (score 1):

Guides like [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/) start with an xsd file because they use xjc to create java classes from the XSD definition. xjc creates classes with JaxB annotations (javax.xml.bind.annotation). JaxB is an xml binding specification that has been part of the JDK since 1.6, and it requires that all types from the xsd exist as java classes.

I suggest that you do a tutorial that starts with an xsd an take a look at the auto generated classes. There is nothing to prevent you from writing you own classes instead of generating them from a wsdl, and if you don't refer to external schemas I prefer to do the code only approach (I hate xml configuration).

If you look at the tutorial, the gradle task "getJaxb" will create .java files into "build/generated-sources" compile them and copy them into "build/classes" if you copy the *.java files into "src/main/java" (keep the package structure) and delete delete/disable the "genJaxb" task in gradle, and delete your build folder, everything still works (it actually works better since you normally have red lines in your IDE because the XML beans don't exist until you run the generator the first time).

Now all you need to do is master the JaxB annotations, so you can write your own beans.